# How can I use "np.argmax()" instead of "classifier.predict_classes()"?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Since `classifier.predict_classes()` got depreciated how can I use below lines of codes using `np.argmax()`.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model

classifier=load_model("cats_vs_dogs_V1.h5")

def draw_test(name, pred, input_im):
    BLACK = [0,0,0]
    if pred == "[0]":
        pred = "cat"
    if pred == "[1]":
        pred = "dog"
    
    expanded_image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(input_im, 0, 0, 0, imageL.shape[0] ,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=BLACK)
    #expanded_image = cv2.cvtColor(expanded_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    
    cv2.putText(expanded_image, str(pred), (252, 200) , cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,4, (23,0,255), 2)
    
    cv2.imshow(name, expanded_image)


for i in range(0,10):
    rand = np.random.randint(0,len(X_test))
    input_im = X_test[rand]

    imageL = cv2.resize(input_im, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    cv2.imshow("Test Image", imageL)

    input_im = input_im.reshape(1,150,150,3) 
    
    ## Get Prediction
    res = str(classifier.predict_classes(input_im, 1, verbose = 0)[0])

    draw_test("Prediction", res, imageL) 
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried replacing `str(classifier.predict_classes(input_im, 1, verbose = 0)[0])` with `str(np.argmax(classifier.predict(input_im, 1, verbose = 0)[0]))` but didn't got the desired output.

Expected Image(displays name)
[image: Expected Image(displays name)]

Image I got(displays 0 only)
[image: Image I got(displays 0 only)]

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not in using `np.argmax()`. You did it correct with `str(np.argmax(classifier.predict(input_im, 1, verbose = 0)[0]))`. However, it returns `"0"` or `"1"` instead of `"[0]"` or `"[1]"`. Thus, you need to fix your `draw_test()` function.

```
def draw_test(name, pred, input_im):
    BLACK = [0,0,0]
    input_dict = {"0":"cat", "1":"dog"}
    pred = input_dict[pred]

    expanded_image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(input_im, 0, 0, 0, imageL.shape[0] ,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=BLACK)
    #expanded_image = cv2.cvtColor(expanded_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    
    cv2.putText(expanded_image, str(pred), (252, 200) , cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,4, (23,0,255), 2)
    
    cv2.imshow(name, expanded_image)
```

Comment: The model is showing name now. But  It only returns cat. All the dogs are also been returned as cat.   `res = str(np.argmax(classifier.predict(input_im, 1, verbose = 0)))`.  I tried putting `res = str(np.argmax(classifier.predict(input_im, 1, verbose = 0)[0]))`  but no changes.

Comment: I think that's a **model issue, not a code error**. Try `draw_test("Prediction", "1", <image array>)`. It should return `dog`. You may need to retrain your model with more samples and less biased training samples.

Comment: putting "1" shows only dogs now. I retrained model. I don't think error is with my code,because `classifier.predict_classes(input_im, 1, verbose = 0)[0])` shows correct unbiased output.  [Link to my github ](https://github.com/sumit-mandal/DeepLearning-opencvProj/blob/main/DogvsCat.ipynb)